# Using QXmlStreamWriter to add text at end of file

Tags: xml, file, qt, text

I have an QXmlStreamWriter and add some xml to it. It works the first time okay, but it doesn't work when I want to use it to add text to the end of a file.

The result I got is the first few lines of good and formatted xml, and the second part containing everything on one line.

How do I fix this?

Comment: "but when i want to add text at end of file it dont work."

I am not sure what you mean by that? Do you try to write using two stream writers? or add plain text at the end?
Maybe it becomes more clear if you present some code.

Comment: Can you show us some code and an example of what its output is?

Answer (score 0):

Use following code if you see all the XML file in one line. (I think you mean you get all the file in one line.)

```
QXmlStreamWriter stream(&file);
stream.setAutoFormatting(true);
stream.setAutoFormattingIndent(2);
```